# Syntax coloring stopped working after updating TeXworks to 0.4.6

Tags: miktex, texworks

Today I updated TeXworks editor (from the MikTeX 2.9 update tool) to version 0.4.6 and the syntax highlighting is not working any longer.

Is there some workaround I may apply to solve the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a bug report in the miktex bug tracker: https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2375/. It's a rather bad bug report as it is very vage and even doesn't mention "texworks". You could improve it.

Comment: Bug report accepted 6 minutes ago!  Cheers!  I have my fingers crossed.

Comment: And it's fixed!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as the bug has been fixed.